# how to search string stored serialized

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search the computer  from this table and when i have stored this in database so now can find the string and pass to the query so it this string present in  database then show result

i am doing

1. i am getting the value form the url my url looks like localhost\demo\article.php?filter=computer

   `$_GET['filter']`
2. my database is

   ```
   id | name |tag

   1  |java  |a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Computer";i:1;s:4:"Code"; 

   2  |dbms  |a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Computer";i:1;s:4:"dbms"; 

   3  |c     |a:2:{i:0;s:8:"elect";i:1;s:4:"Code";
   ```

now i am want to fetch all the row where the computer is present or code

for that i am using the query

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE tag='%".$_GET['filter']."%' ";
```

but its not showing the row having the computer or code..

**its like the stackoverflow tag filtration**

Comment: Are you sure that you can't change your current structure? I don't think, it's a good idea to make searches in serialized strings. By the way, using like instead of equal will do what you want (as suggested in one of the answers below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solving your problem is by replacing `=` with `like` so your query should be

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE tag like '%".$_GET['filter']."%' ";
```

a better way of doing this, is to create extra two tables. One will contain your tags (optional) and the other will contain tagging information.

[image]

[This article](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Comprehensive-Guide-to-PHP-MySQL-Tag-Clouds-Includes-Demo) will help you so much

Answer (score 4):

[Normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and you will no longer need to turn a nail with a screwdriver.

Comment: its like the stackoverflow tag filtration now would you mind make me understand how to do this?

Comment: click the link :) Create a second table, so you can add multiple values to each of your entities.

Comment: @StefanN: No use, he'll probably just use Adnan's answer and keep his horribly broken schema.